# How to create histogram from grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to create histogram from grouped data in pandas.

So far I was able to create standard line plot. But I can't figure out how to do the same to get histogram (bar chart). I would like to get 2 age histograms of persons who survived Titanic crush and who didn't - to see if there is a difference in age distribution.

Source data:
https://www.udacity.com/api/nodes/5454512672/supplemental_media/titanic-datacsv/download

So far my code:

```
import pandas as pn
titanic = pn.DataFrame.from_csv('titanic_data.csv')

SurvivedAge= titanic.groupby(['Survived','Age']).size()
SurvivedAge=SurvivedAge.reset_index()
SurvivedAge.columns=['Survived', 'Age', 'Num']
SurvivedAge.index=(SurvivedAge['Survived'])
del SurvivedAge['Survived']

SurvivedAget=SurvivedAge.reset_index().pivot('Age', 'Survived','Num')

SurvivedAget.plot()
```

when I'm trying to plot a histogram from this data set I'm getting strange results.

```
SurvivedAget.hist()
```

I would be grateful for help with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

```
titanic = pd.read_csv('titanic_data.csv')
survival_by_age = titanic.groupby(['Age', 'Survived']).size().unstack('Survived')
survival_by_age.columns = ['No', 'Yes']
survival_by_age.plot.bar(title='Survival by Age')
```

to get:

[image]

which you can further [tweak](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). You could also consolidate the fractional ages so you can use integer indices, or [bin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.cut.html) the data into say 5yr age spans to get more user-friendly output. And then there is [seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html#seaborn.jointplot) with a various types of distribution plots.