# How to Create Double or Stacked Bar Graph Using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How do you create a grouped or stacked bar graph using three sets of value_counts() data from a csv file in Python? I can successfully graph each set individually using this code:

```py
dfwidget1.country.value_counts().plot('bar', color='blue')
```

I don't know, however, how to get them all to plot onto the same graph. Obviously this, which I've tried, doesn't work:

```py
dfwidget1.country.value_counts().plot('bar', color='blue')
dfwidget2.country.value_counts().plot('bar', color='red')
dfwidget3.country.value_counts().plot('bar', color='yellow')
```

After researching, I've also tried using groupby(), but without success. If that's the way to go, I'd appreciate affirmation along those lines, and I'll go study up. If there is a simpler way to do it, I'm all ears.

Here's the toy df (saved as widget-by-country.csv):

[image: Toy DataFrame]

Here's the code I've tried:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

%matplotlib inline
sns.set()

df = pd.read_csv('widget-by-country.csv')

dfwidget1 = df[df['category'].str.contains('widget1', na=False)]
dfwidget2 = df[df['category'].str.contains('widget2', na=False)]
dfwidget3 = df[df['category'].str.contains('widget3', na=False)]

dfwidget1.country.value_counts().plot('bar', color='blue')
dfwidget2.country.value_counts().plot('bar', color='red')
dfwidget3.country.value_counts().plot('bar', color='yellow')
```

This is what I get, which does not show me the full distribution of countries where each widget is made:

[image]

I'd really like to see a grouped bar graph showing this data that looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: I re-wrote my question with a toy df.

Comment: Have you seen the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878948/how-to-create-histogram-from-grouped-data